# pdf Distribution of Trace of Inverse Wishart matrix

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices

Im tring to find an expression for the pdf of Trace of Inverse Wishart matrix? Can anyone help me with that?

In other words, Suppose you need to calculate the distribution of $\text{Tr}\left(\left(HH^H\right)^{-1}\right)$ where H is the gaussian distributed random matrix.

Comment: Are your gaussian variables standard ?

Comment: yes standered gaussian distribution

Comment: Do you know about the joint distribution of eigenvalues of $HH^H$ ?

Comment: actually no? can you give me some details?

Comment: look at this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution